# Não consigo fazer um evento onchange para mudar uma foto quando selecionamos o campo select

Tags: javascript, html

Quando seleciono uma opção do select teria q aparecer uma imagem diferente no img que eu criei, mas não tá funcionando.

Código HTML

```
<select id="produtos" onchange="mudaFoto()">
   <option value="">Selecione o Produto</option>
   <option value="ac-uniao">Áçúcar Refinado união</option>
   <option value="ac-guarani">Áçúcar Refinado Guarani</option>
   <option value="AM">AM</option>
</select>
```

Código Javascript

```
var foto = document.getElementById('imagem-produto').src;

function mudaFoto() {
    switch(document.getElementById('produtos').selectedIndex()) {
    case 1: foto = "_imagens/acucar-uniao.png";
    break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você deve referenciar o elemento na variável `foto`: como o valor é uma `string` ela será pega por valor, e não por referência; o elemento, por sua vez, sendo um objeto, será pego por referência.

```
var foto = document.getElementById('imagem-produto');

function mudaFoto() {
    switch(document.getElementById('produtos').selectedIndex) {
      case 1:
      foto.src = "_imagens/acucar-uniao.png";
      break;
    }
}
```

Também há de considerar que `.selectedIndex` não é uma função e sim uma propriedade do `<select>`. Dependendo dos casos pode-se usar `.value`, porém isso é uma escolha sua.

Comment: fiz as alterações exatamente iguais, mas não está entrando no switch, testei o case 1 com alerte e ainda não tá funcionando.

Comment: Arrumei o switch para ter mais opções e troquei as imagens para o teste, olhe: http://jsbin.com/busepuma/1/edit

Comment: Boa explicação. +1

Answer (score 2):

Tenta assim

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){

        mudaFoto();
    }

    function mudaFoto(){
        switch(document.getElementById('produtos').value) {
            case '1': 
                document.getElementById('imagem-produto').src = "_imagens/acucar-uniao.png";

            break;
            case '2': 
                document.getElementById('imagem-produto').src = "_imagens/acucsr-uniao.png";

            break;
        }
    }
</script>

 <select id="produtos" onchange="return mudaFoto();">
   <option value="">Selecione o Produto</option>
   <option value="1">Áçúcar Refinado união</option>
   <option value="2">Áçúcar Refinado Guarani</option>
   <option value="3">AM</option>
 </select><br /><br />

 <img id="imagem-produto" src="teste.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
```

Comment: Agora sim, funcionou de boa, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

O Gustavo já deu uma boa resposta (já aceite) acerca de de como referenciar o elemento e o selectIndex. Deixo mais uma resposta para acrescentar uma outra maneira de pensar o código.

Assim em vez de usar switch/case pode usar assim:

```
var select = document.getElementById('produtos');
var foto = document.getElementById('imagem-produto');
select.addEventListener('change', function () {  // correr uma função quando o select muda
    foto.src = this.value; // atribuir o value da opção à .src da foto
});
```

Esta opção implica o seu select/opções ter no value o nome da foto.

Exemplo:

```
<option value="acucar-uniao">Áçúcar Refinado união</option>  
//acucar-uniao em vez de ac-uniao
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    window.onload = function(){

        mudaFoto();
    }

    function mudaFoto(){
        switch(document.getElementById('produtos').value) {
            case '1': 
                document.getElementById('imagem-produto').src = "_imagens/acucar-uniao.png";

            break;
            case '2': 
                document.getElementById('imagem-produto').src = "_imagens/acucsr-uniao.png";

            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rafael, bemvindo ao StackOverflow_PT! Imagino que esta resposta faze parte da resposta acima? assim pode apagar esta e se necessário editar a resposta em cima. Cumprimentos!